# multiple fragments in single tab (right now its fragment) in fragmentactivity

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm working with fragmentactivity which has **5 tabs** (fragments).. what I need is that first tab1 has **Enter** button and clicking that would switch to another fragment within tab1 without getting any weird result like right now this is what I'm doing in onClickListener

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(Frag_Home.this);
ft.commit();                    
Frag_Locations newFragment = new Frag_Locations();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

transaction.commit();
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

**Code above changes the content but newly added fragment covers the whole view and newly opened fragment floats above tabs!!

how can add fragmentactivity in tab1 instead of fragment?? (BTW I followed **http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/** tutorial)

**Edit**

**tab1** => fragmentOne (onButtonClick replaces)  => fragmentTwo (click) =>fragmentThree

**tab2** => fragmentForth

**tab3** => fragmentFifth

this is what I want

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get solution for this problem, because I'm also stuck with this.

Comment: @SathisKumar, I can't post clean answer but its pretty clean to know how I end up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I end up..

People might know about adding fragment in tab

```
// HashMap for storing fragments so we could track them by their names
private HashMap mapTabInfo = new HashMap();

  // This one is the normal way to add fragment to tab (mine is customized so better look into some nice tutorial for better understading)
tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), MY_TICKET, R.drawable.tab_icon_myticket_selector);
            MainTabActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec(MY_TICKET).setIndicator(tabview),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo(MY_TICKET, Frag_MyTicket.class, args)));

    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    // Add these fragments here so we can track them by own interface's method 
    tabInfo = new TabInfo(LOCATIONS, Frag_Locations.class, args);
    this.mapTabInfo.put(LOCATIONS, tabInfo);

// These two fragments won't show up in tabs untill we make it display manually 
    tabInfo = new TabInfo(DAYS, Frag_Days.class, args);
    this.mapTabInfo.put(DAYS, tabInfo);

// Now when we want to show fragment LOCATION while showing My_TICKET fragment, we'll just call method
onTabChanged(String tag) // method called when tabs are tapped, call this method with string LOCATIONS and you are done there..

// I know this might not be easiest to understand, you'll understand the logic if you're familiar with fragments/tabs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really good example of how to use tabs with `Fragments` in `ActionBarSherlock's` examples : [Fragments Example](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java). Take a look, I think this is the thing which you want to achieve. : )

Comment: I guess I've implemented pretty much same but with compatibility library.. I might not askd vey well.. please check the edited question.. thanks

Comment: You can still use this tab adapter from the example without using ABS library.

Comment: I appreciate your help but can you please throw me a hint? I'm not getting your point (sorry if it offends you!) thanks

Comment: You want to be able to navigate Fragments and keep the tab bar at the bottom right? So take a look at the code more carefully: you have TabManager class which actually holds the fragments for you. Just need to add a listener in your FragmentActivity and replace the fragments on some kind of event (onButtonClick for example).

Comment: yes i understand that, try this example and you will achieve this.

Comment: @Android-Developer: link is broken

Comment: @iDroidExplorer link is updated. Thanks for the information. : )